# Azure WebApp - How to restart individual instance using Powershell or API

Tags: powershell, azure, web-applications, azure-powershell, azure-web-app-service

We are running a WebApp with 3 instances. We would like to restart these instances at night individually. Im trying to find a Powershell or REST API solution to work along with a cron job but I'm only coming up with solutions to restart the entire WebApp.

We are aware of the manual process to restart them (screenshot link below) but we would like to automate the process.

[Screenshot link.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsZ7U.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could use Azure Power Shell to do this, please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810248/powershell-for-an-advanced-application-restart-on-an-azure-web-app).

According to your description, I suggest you could firstly find each instance's process in your web app by using `Get-AzureRmResource` command. Then you could use `Remove-AzureRmResource` to stop these processes. Then when you access the azure web application, azure will automatic create new instance's process to run your application.

More details, you could refer to below powershell codes:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId '{your subscriptionid}'

$siteName = "{sitename}"
$rgGroup = "{groupname}" 

$webSiteInstances = @()

#This gives you list of instances
$webSiteInstances = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $rgGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/instances -ResourceName $siteName -ApiVersion 2015-11-01 

$sub = (Get-AzureRmContext).Subscription.SubscriptionId 

foreach ($instance in $webSiteInstances)
{
    $instanceId = $instance.Name
    "Going to enumerate all processes on {0} instance" -f $instanceId 

    # This gives you list of processes running
    # on a particular instance
    $processList =  Get-AzureRmResource `
                    -ResourceId /subscriptions/$sub/resourceGroups/$rgGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$sitename/instances/$instanceId/processes `
                    -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 

    foreach ($process in $processList)
    {               
        if ($process.Properties.Name -eq "w3wp")
        {            
            $resourceId = "/subscriptions/$sub/resourceGroups/$rgGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$sitename/instances/$instanceId/processes/" + $process.Properties.Id            
            $processInfoJson = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId  $resourceId  -ApiVersion 2015-08-01                                     

            # is_scm_site is a property which is set
            # on the worker process for the KUDU 

                $computerName = $processInfoJson.Properties.Environment_variables.COMPUTERNAME

                if ($processInfoJson.Properties.is_scm_site -ne $true)
            {
                $computerName = $processInfoJson.Properties.Environment_variables.COMPUTERNAME
                "Instance ID" + $instanceId  + "is for " +   $computerName

                "Going to stop this process " + $processInfoJson.Name + " with PID " + $processInfoJson.Properties.Id

                # Remove-AzureRMResource finally STOPS the worker process
                $result = Remove-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $resourceId -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force 

                if ($result -eq $true)
                { 
                    "Process {0} stopped " -f $processInfoJson.Properties.Id
                }
            }       
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: awesome I've tested it and works. Glad you were able to help because my Azure Support Engineer said there is no way to do it so i got discouraged there. :)

Comment: @KentRozenberg If my answer works, please don't forget to accept it as  an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at Windows Azure PowerShell Cmdlets, the Command you want to use is Reset-AzureRoleInstance ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152835.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Azure/Reset-AzureRoleInstance?view=azuresmps-4.0.0))

Comment: This only supports ASM model?

Comment: @ThuanNg  This is a wrong answer. It only works for Azure Cloud Server(classic), the OP want to restart instance for web app.

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT
Thats correct its type a App Service instance

Comment: @KentRozenberg It is possible, you could check my answer.