# Advanced Application Restart - powershell (Azure CLI)

Tags: azure, powershell

Following on from this question: 
[Powershell for an Advanced Application Restart on an Azure Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810248/powershell-for-an-advanced-application-restart-on-an-azure-web-app?noredirect=1&lq=1)

My command doesn't have any processes returned from the 3rd call to Get-AzureRmResource. I am using Azure Powershell April 2018 (v5.7.0). The first two calls to Get-AzureRmResource work. I simply get an output of

```
Going to enumerate all processes on 1c0499509f00dc4dde75497ea121d4d32c850ad32xxxxxxxxxxxxxx instance
Going to enumerate all processes on 833b0f35d4116cc4392ec0620f22ce7fa355f801be9a8axxxxxxxxxxxx instance.
```

Any ideas why this could be?

I have tried:

- Matching the API version or removing that flag altogether
- Referencing the RG name and resource name instead of the ID
- Using a different command to list the processes
- Running in ISE and vanilla powershell

Using the portal or Kudu console does show me processes for each instance.

Comment: What does the variable `$webSiteInstances` contain? Are there two or three instances listed?

Comment: Two instances - those listed there

Comment: Then possibly the third instance you are expecting does not belong to the same ResourceGroup as the others, or you should rethink the value for `ResourceName`? (This parameter supports wildcards at the beginning and/or end of the string)

Comment: Ah - I mean the 3rd call in the code listing that is linked at the top of the question (which is the call that lists the processes). I'm just expecting processes to be listed for the two instances there

Comment: OK, sorry, but then I don't understand what your question is about..