# Azure Webapp Service bus force restart

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azureservicebus

I have an issue with azure resources.
I have a resource group with 2 web apps, one is a WebApp Api and the second is a WebApp for service bus.

I never face this issue and never realised of its existence till yesterday. The dynamic of the event is as follow.

In some specific scenarios, when I update my Api (only api) I run a new release which it deploy the new content and restart the web app (in this case, the pipeline targets Api and service), but yesterday I realise that if I updated the Api and don't touch the service and run my pipeline, azure DevOps, doesn't create a new realise for service, but reply deploys the old one as there where no changes.

I don't mind about creating a brand new realise (which will be good anyway) but I need this process to automate the restart of this web app service.

Here is my problem which I home somebody can help me to solve.

Is there a way in which I can force a web app to simply restart and update, or force it to create a new realise even if the code didn't change?

Thank you so much for your time and help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Web Apps-Restart

**HTTP**

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/restart?api-version=2019-08-01
```

With optional parameters:

**HTTP**

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/restart?softRestart={softRestart}&synchronous={synchronous}&api-version=2019-08-01
```

**Powershell**

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId '{your subscriptionid}'

$siteName = "{sitename}"
$rgGroup = "{groupname}" 

$webSiteInstances = @()

#This gives you list of instances
$webSiteInstances = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $rgGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/instances -ResourceName $siteName -ApiVersion 2015-11-01 

$sub = (Get-AzureRmContext).Subscription.SubscriptionId 

foreach ($instance in $webSiteInstances)
{
    $instanceId = $instance.Name
    "Going to enumerate all processes on {0} instance" -f $instanceId 

    # This gives you list of processes running
    # on a particular instance
    $processList =  Get-AzureRmResource `
                    -ResourceId /subscriptions/$sub/resourceGroups/$rgGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$sitename/instances/$instanceId/processes `
                    -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 

    foreach ($process in $processList)
    {               
        if ($process.Properties.Name -eq "w3wp")
        {            
            $resourceId = "/subscriptions/$sub/resourceGroups/$rgGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$sitename/instances/$instanceId/processes/" + $process.Properties.Id            
            $processInfoJson = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId  $resourceId  -ApiVersion 2015-08-01                                     

            # is_scm_site is a property which is set
            # on the worker process for the KUDU 

                $computerName = $processInfoJson.Properties.Environment_variables.COMPUTERNAME

                if ($processInfoJson.Properties.is_scm_site -ne $true)
            {
                $computerName = $processInfoJson.Properties.Environment_variables.COMPUTERNAME
                "Instance ID" + $instanceId  + "is for " +   $computerName

                "Going to stop this process " + $processInfoJson.Name + " with PID " + $processInfoJson.Properties.Id

                # Remove-AzureRMResource finally STOPS the worker process
                $result = Remove-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $resourceId -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force 

                if ($result -eq $true)
                { 
                    "Process {0} stopped " -f $processInfoJson.Properties.Id
                }
            }       
       }

    }
}
```

You can refer to
[Web Apps - Restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/restart),
[How to automatically restart an app service after certain time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45588260/how-to-automatically-restart-an-app-service-after-certain-time/59633629#59633629) ,and
[Powershell for an Advanced Application Restart on an Azure Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810248/powershell-for-an-advanced-application-restart-on-an-azure-web-app)